# Add private GitHub repo to pyproject.toml as new dependency

Tags: python, pyproject.toml

How can I define a private GitHub repo as a dependency in the `project` section of my `pyproject.toml` file?

```
[project]
dependencies = [
    "my_repo_name>=<SSH-address_to_my_private_github_repo>"
]
```

Comment: [This](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#dependencies-and-dev-dependencies) should help

Comment: What is the build back-end used in this project? Setuptools or something else?

Answer (score 17):

How about something like:

```
dependencies = [
    "my_pkg_name @ git+ssh://git@github.com/my-github-name/my_repo",
]
```

Explanation:

@EDG956 and @sinoroc pointed at docs on how to do this if you're using [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), but *I don't think you are*: your example has a `[project]` section rather than a `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` section, so I'm guessing you're using `pyproject.toml` with `setuptools` directly — as described [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html).

That page refers to PEP 621, whose [section on `dependencies`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/#dependencies-optional-dependencies) says:

> For `dependencies`, it is a key whose value is an array of strings. Each string represents a dependency of the project and MUST be formatted as a valid PEP 508 string.

Then, [the "Examples" section of PEP 508](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#examples) shows an example which I've used as the basis of my suggestion above.

(As usual, you can use `@<tag>` or `@<sha>`, or `#<branch_name>` suffixes, etc.)

Comment: Right, I do not know why I assumed it is about Poetry. Thanks for rectifying. -- If I recall correctly, it should also be noted that such "direct references" will be rejected by PyPI (and maybe some other index servers as well).

Comment: Don't forget to add the following settings to the pyproject.toml  

[tool.hatch.metadata]
allow-direct-references = true