# How can I correctly show the dependents of my Python package on GitHub given a conflicting repo?

Tags: github, dependencies

I'm one of the maintainers of https://pypi.org/project/pretext. We previously used the more verbose `pretextbook` namespace, but the maintainer of an inactive `pretext` project graciously offered the name to us.

On GitHub, it seems that the [repository archive](https://github.com/moreati/b-prefix-all-the-doctests) for this old project is getting the "Used By" information in GitHub's dependency graph instead of our [active repository](https://github.com/PreTeXtBook/pretext-cli). Is there any way to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known GitHub bug and as of 2023 June 07 a support ticket must be filed to correct it. See https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/34687#discussioncomment-6111505

Comment: Good update. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The `pretext-cli` repository is using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/) and a `pyproject.toml` file for dependency management, instead of a `setup.py` or `requirements.txt` file.

The [`setup.py` file](https://github.com/PreTeXtBook/pretext-cli/blob/main/setup.py) in the `pretext-cli` repository is not a real `setup.py` file - it simply raises an exception. This could be one reason why GitHub's dependency graph isn't picking up the correct dependencies for `pretext-cli`.

And that assumes there is no syntax issue in said `pyproject.toml` file, as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73572379/6309).

---

Reading "[About the dependency graph](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/understanding-your-software-supply-chain/about-the-dependency-graph)", and "[Using the Dependency submission API](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/understanding-your-software-supply-chain/using-the-dependency-submission-api)", I see that GitHub's dependency graph is a summary of the manifest and lock files stored in a (public) repository and any dependencies that are submitted to the repository using the Dependency submission API (beta).
It shows the dependencies and dependents of each repository.

The dependency graph is updated automatically when:

- a commit is pushed to GitHub that changes or adds a supported manifest or lock file to the default branch.
- anyone pushes a change to the repository of one of your dependencies​.

For the most reliable graph, lock files (or their equivalent) should be used because they define exactly which versions of the direct and indirect dependencies you currently use​.

`poetry.lock` and `pyproject.toml` (but your repository does not have a lock file).
You could try to list your dependencies in a `pyproject.toml` file *and* a `poetry.lock` file, which are supported by the GitHub dependency graph for the Python Poetry package ecosystem​.

You may also consider using the Dependency submission API (beta) to manually submit dependencies for your project to the GitHub dependency graph.

In the case of a name conflict with the older repository, it might be worthwhile to reach out to GitHub support directly and explain the situation.

---

As noted by the [OP Steven Clontz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1607849/steven-clontz) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75851255/how-can-i-correctly-show-the-dependents-of-my-python-package-on-github-given-a-c/76276636#comment134532730_76276636), [discussion 34687 "Dependency Graph not showing any dependents when there should be"](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/34687) reports an internal issue in progress.

Comment: I'm skeptical it's the setup.py that's at fault here, though I've removed it and unignored our poetry.lock. But your suggestion to contact support pointed me to https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/34687#discussioncomment-4894441 so perhaps this is just broken.

Comment: @StevenClontz Good catch. I have included your comment and discussion reference in the answer for more visibility.